# How to remove object from linked list

Tags: java

I have a linked list containing all of my students(which are objects)

I want to be able to remove a student based on the id I pass in

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Registry

{
    LinkedList<student> Students = new LinkedList<student>();
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Registry() {
    }

    public void addStudents() {

        System.out.println("Add a new student");
        System.out.println("Enter ForeName");
        String foreName = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter SurName");
        String surName = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Student ID");
        String studentID = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Degree Scheme");
        String degreeScheme = myObj.nextLine();
        Students.add(new student(foreName, surName, studentID, degreeScheme));
    }

    public LinkedList<student> getStudents() {
        return Students;
    }

    public void deleteStudent() {
    System.out.println("Enter the ID of the student you want to remove");
    String studentID = myObj.nextLine();
    Students.remove(student)
    }
}
```

In the `deleteStudent` method I do not know how to locate the student with the id

I then presume I can just use `.remove(student)` to remove the student?

How can I locate the student with the id?

Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you can do is iterate through the LinkedList to find a student with same studentID and remove that from the LinkedList.

```
for(Student student:getStudents()){
    if(student.studentID.equals(studentID)) students.remove(student);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`Collection::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
Students.removeIf(student -> Objects.equals(student.getId(), studentId));
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/p0bQoG)

(The code snippet assumes a `getId()` method on `Student` and that the types of `studentId` and `Student::getId` are [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html))

A remark on the code: In java, field names should be written in `camleCase` (`LinkedList<student> Students ...` -> `LinkedList<student> students ...`)